# How make the fill button fill default values in RapiDoc and somebody to use the values to try?

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a RapiDoc for an API documentation, clear button and try are working fine but i want when somebody needs to try he/she should not in put the vales in fields instead to fill default values by clicking fill button then try. How do i do that?.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenAPI spec you can provide example for parameter. 'Fill Example' Button will work only when you have provided example values in your OpenAPI spec